# Looking to store an int in a char array via its equivalent ASCII value in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, ascii

I'm calculating some numbers (in between 0 and 255) and I'm wanting to store them in a `char` array in C using their ASCII equivalents.

Is there a nice way of doing this?

```
int b = (int)(*pixelA.pixel_b * (1-w) * (1-h) +
              *pixelB.pixel_b * (w) * (1-h) +
              *pixelC.pixel_b * (1-w) * (h) +
              *pixelD.pixel_b * (w*h));

modified_Frame[k] = (char)b;
```

That's the kind of thing I'm aiming for, if the `(char)` meant it took the value of `b`, and wrote the ASCII equivalent into the array.

I tried using both pointers (hoping that C would just do it automatically) like so:

```
int *pb = &b;   
modified_Frame[k] = *pb;
```

And using chars for `b` rather than an `int`; however it just seems to send block data back, so I'm guessing it doesn't work how I'm intending it to.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit to give more information:

I'm reading in a byte array, saving it to a char array, then trying to perform some bilinear interpolation on it, before sending the modified version back. The code below shows most of the process.

When I say ASCII equivalents, it's because they're bytes, and so can vary from 0-255 and that seems to be the ASCII equivalents from a little playing about (for instance filling the array with 'z' resulted in a value of 122 being sent across).

```
n = read(conn_desc, &framebuff[ntotal], incomingframesize-ntotal);

char modified_Frame[((incomingframesize*4)-(54*3))];

for (i=0;i<newYSize;i++)
{
    y = (int)(y_ratio * i);
    for (j=0;j<newXSize;j++)
    {
        x = (int)(x_ratio * j);
        w = (x_ratio * j) - x;
        h = (y_ratio * i) - y;

        pixelA.pixel_b = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_B(x,y)];
        pixelA.pixel_g = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_G(x,y)];
        pixelA.pixel_r = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_R(x,y)];

        pixelB.pixel_b = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_B(x+1,y)];
        pixelB.pixel_g = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_G(x+1,y)];
        pixelB.pixel_r = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_R(x+1,y)];

        pixelC.pixel_b = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_B(x,y+1)];
        pixelC.pixel_g = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_G(x,y+1)];
        pixelC.pixel_r = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_R(x,y+1)];

        pixelD.pixel_b = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_B(x+1,y+1)];
        pixelD.pixel_g = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_G(x+1,y+1)];
        pixelD.pixel_r = &framebuff[GET_PIXEL_R(x+1,y+1)];


        int r = (int)(*pixelA.pixel_r * (1-w) * (1-h) + *pixelB.pixel_r * (w) * (1-h) + *pixelC.pixel_r * (1-w) * (h) + *pixelD.pixel_r * (w*h));
        int g = (int)(*pixelA.pixel_g * (1-w) * (1-h) + *pixelB.pixel_g * (w) * (1-h) + *pixelC.pixel_g * (1-w) * (h) + *pixelD.pixel_g * (w*h));
        int b = (int)(*pixelA.pixel_b * (1-w) * (1-h) + *pixelB.pixel_b * (w) * (1-h) + *pixelC.pixel_b * (1-w) * (h) + *pixelD.pixel_b * (w*h));

        modified_Frame[k] = b;
        k++;
        modified_Frame[k] = g;
        k++;
        modified_Frame[k] = r;
        k++;
    }
}
```

This is an attempt at 'translating' a C# algorithm I had working from a while back.

Comment: is modified_Frame a char*?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the first equation always generates numbers between 0 and 255. But if it does and if `modified_Frame` is an array of `unsigned char`, then `modified_Frame[k] = (unsigned char)b;` should work.

Comment: The cast is redundant

Comment: modified_Frame is just a char[]. I think it should, although I haven't done much testing of the algorithm yet. So Matt you're saying I could just try the first section of code without the cast?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: the redundancy of the cast depends on the level of warnings under which you compile.  Compiling with `clang -Weverything` and the cast is required.  Whether it is sensible to compile with `clang -Weverything` is a separate discussion.

Comment: You haven't really said what the problem is.  Are you getting a compile error?  Is the result incorrect?  Is it possible for you to show a short complete example of how you arrive at the result and what the problem is with it?  When you talk about a value between 0 and 255 and then then mention ASCII (0 to 127) it gets a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm compiling with this line: gcc server.c -ggdb3 -o server. I'm fairly new to coding on linux so I just went with what I read from various examples. Having just tried it without the cast, I get the same result, the data coming back is just repeated for each pixel of the image. I guess if you guys are saying that the code should work the problem must be somewhere in my algorithm, I'll take another looksie.

It's running, just that the data I'm receiving from modified_Frame is repeated sets of 3 numbers which shouldn't be happening as far as I'm aware. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
perhaps the following would work for you.

int main()
{
    int myint = 25;  //could actually be any int value 0...255

    char mychar;

    mychar = (char)(myint&0xFF);

    return (int)mychar;
}
```

Comment: All the above casts are redundant. Types less than int are always promoted to int (or unsigned int). Assigning a value to a narrower type will truncate that value